# Memory leak using TIdHTTP and TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL

Tags: delphi-xe5, indy10

I have the following class

```
type
  TMyDownload = class
  private
    FHttp: TIdHttp;
    function VerifyPeer(Certificate: TIdX509; AOk: Boolean; ADepth, AError: Integer): Boolean;
  public
    constructor Create(const ARootCertFile: string);
    destructor Destroy; override;
    function Get(const URL: string; Stream: TStream): Integer;
  end;

constructor TMyDownload.Create(const ARootCertFile: string);
begin
  inherited Create;

  FHttp := TIdHTTP.Create;
  FHttp.Compressor := TIdCompressorZLib.Create(FHttp);
  FHttp.IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(FHttp);
  FHttp.HandleRedirects := True;
  FHttp.ProtocolVersion := pv1_1;
  FHttp.ConnectTimeout := 10000;
  FHttp.ReadTimeout := 10000;
  FHttp.AllowCookies := True;

  with TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL(FHttp.IOHandler) do
  begin
    OnVerifyPeer := VerifyPeer;
    SSLOptions.Mode := sslmClient;
    SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1_2;
    SSLOptions.RootCertFile := ARootCertFile;
    SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1_2];
    SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [sslvrfPeer, sslvrfFailIfNoPeerCert, sslvrfClientOnce];
    SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 5;
  end;
end;

destructor TMyDownload.Destroy;
begin
  FreeAndNil(FHttp);
  inherited;
end;

function TMyDownload.Get(const URL: string; Stream: TStream): Integer;
begin
  try
    FHttp.Get(URL, Stream, [304]);
    Exit(FHttp.ResponseCode);
  except
    LogException(ClassName, False, True);
    Result := 500;
  end;
end;

function TMyDownload.VerifyPeer(Certificate: TIdX509; AOk: Boolean; ADepth, AError: Integer): Boolean;
var
  CurrentTime: TDateTime;
begin
  if (ADepth = 0) then
  begin
    if AOk and (AError = 0) then
    begin
      CurrentTime := Now;
      Result := (Pos('/CN=' + UpperCase(FHttp.URL.Host) + '/', '/' + UpperCase(Certificate.Subject.OneLine) + '/') <> 0)
                and (CurrentTime >= Certificate.notBefore)
                and (CurrentTime <= Certificate.notAfter);
    end
    else
      Result := False;
  end
  else
    Result := AOk and (AError = 0);
end;
```

which is repeatedly used (every minute) in the following manner:

```
// cacert.pem obtained from https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html
MyDownload := TMyDownload.Create('cacert.pem');
try
  Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    MyDownload.Get('https://www.google.com/', Stream);
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
finally
  MyDownload.Free;
end;
```

The above code constitutes the entirety of the program. If it runs for 3 to five days, the program runs out of memory (on Win32 consumes 2+GB). If I disable the

```
SSLOptions.RootCertFile := ARootCertFile;
```

The program runs fine, but with the downside of having to accept unsecure chain certificates.

Is there something I am missing, could any one point me in the right direction

Comment: I see nothing in this code that would cause a leak. Have you used Delphi's `ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown` to check if real leaks are reported? Perhaps you are experiencing memory fragmentation instead of leaking? It is really hard to tell one way or the other without more information about your app's memory usage

Comment: On a side note, your `Get()` method should return the `FHttp.ResponseCode` if an `EIdHTTPProtocolException` is raised.

Comment: Hi @Remy, trust me it does leak. If I disable the "SSLOptions.RootCertFile" line, it does not leak. and to reiterate, that code represents the entirety of the program

Comment: Just because memory usage is rising over time does not necessarily mean that memory is being **leaked**.  Fragmented memory is not leaked memory.  You need to debug your app deeper to find out which is actually the case.

Comment: What you have showed is NOT the *entirety* of your code, as you did not show the *actual* loop that is calling `TMyDownload.Get()` every 1 minute. But I just now did a test, using the latest SVN revision of Indy 10 with the latest OpenSSL 1.0.2o DLLs from http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/, and running the code *exactly* as you have shown it (including use of the certificate), looping the download every 500ms, memory usage was stable over several minutes.  So something else in your app is likely leaking/fragmenting memory, and you are just attributing it to Indy.

Comment: Also, which platform(s) are you running your code on?  Indy loads the certificate in several different ways depending on the platform used.